# add file to spark driver classpath file on dataproc

Tags: apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

I need to add a config file to driver spark classpath on google dataproc.

I have try to use `--files` option of `gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark` but this not work.

Is there a way to do it on google dataproc?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58238269/add-conf-file-to-classpath-in-google-dataproc/58293749?noredirect=1#comment102962018_58293749

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In Dataproc, anything listed as a --jar will be added to the classpath and anything listed as a --file will be made available in each spark executor's working directory. Even though the flag is --jars, it should be safe to put non-jar entries in this list if you require the file to be on the classpath.

Answer (score 1):

I know, I am answering too late. Posting for new visitors.

One can execute this using cloud shell. Have tested this.

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit spark --properties spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=false --cluster=<cluster_name> --class com.test.PropertiesFileAccess --region=<CLUSTER_REGION> --files gs://<BUCKET>/prod.predleads.properties --jars gs://<BUCKET>/snowflake-common-3.1.34.jar
```

Comment: if i need to access the file, and use it to spark program, how do i do that ? Can i refer to the bucket directly ? or just the name of the file ?