# Copy file from dbfs in cluster-scoped init script

Tags: bash, azure, databricks, azure-databricks

I want to try out cluster scoped init scripts on a Azure Databricks cluster. I'm struggling to see which commands are available.

Basically, I've got a file on dbfs that I want to copy to a local directory `/tmp/config` when the cluster spins up.

So I created a very simple bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash
mkdir - p /tmp/config
databricks fs cp dbfs:/path/to/myFile.conf /tmp/config
```

Spinning up the cluster fails with "Cluster terminated. Reason: Init Script Failure". Looking at the log on dbfs, I see the error

```
bash: line 1: databricks: command not found
```

OK, so `databricks` as a command is not available. That's the command I use on the local bash to copy files from and to dbfs.

What other commands are available to copy a file from dbfs?
And more general: Which commands are actually available?

Comment: Try `compgen -a`.

Comment: Thanks, didn't know ```compgen```. Problem is that I can't see the output of the init script. Tried a redirect, in the init script I have ```compgen -a >&2``` but no output is written to the error log.

Comment: Did you ever fix this? Same issue here.

Comment: No, unfortunately I didn't. We changed our application anyway so the configuration file I tried to copy, doesn't need to be in the classpath anymore. So now I don't need an init script at all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The dbfs is mounted to the clusters, so you can just copy it in your shell script:

e.g.

```
cp /dbfs/your-folder/your-file.txt ./your-file-txt
```

If you do a dir on the /dbfs location you get as a return all the folders/data you have in your dbfs.

You can also first test it in a notebook via

```
%sh
cd /dbfs
dir
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, that should work! Anywhere in the documentation where I can find this?

Comment: I found it here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/databricks/data/databricks-file-system#--local-file-apis

Answer (score 1):

By default, Databricks CLI is not installed on the databricks cluster. That's the reason you see this error message `bash: line 1: databricks: command not found`.

To achieve this, you should use **dbutils** commands as shown below.

```
dbutils.fs.mkdirs("/tmp/config")
dbutils.fs.mv("/configuration/proxy.conf", "/tmp/config")
```

[image]

**Reference:** [Databricks Utilities](https://docs.databricks.com/dev-tools/databricks-utils.html)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Aren't dbutils only available in the notebooks? I don't see how I can use it in a cluster init script.

Comment: databricks and dbutils cannot be runned using init scripts, you should use Notebooks or Azure Databricks cli to accomplish these.

Comment: Tried it in a notebook, but doesn't do what I'm looking for. Executed ```dbutils.fs.mkdirs("/tmp/config")``` followed by ```dbutils.fs.cp("dbfs:/conf/application.conf","/tmp/config/")```, but when looking at it with ```dbutils.fs.ls("/tmp/config")``` it shows that the file was copied to dbfs again: ```Out[22]: [FileInfo(path='dbfs:/tmp/config/application.conf', name='application.conf', size=4742)]``` The documentation says you can copy "across FileSystems", but I can't see how to specify the local filesystem of the driver node.