# Submit a pyspark job with a config file on Dataproc

Tags: google-cloud-platform, pyspark, submit, jobs, google-cloud-dataproc

I'm newbie on GCP and I'm struggling with submitting pyspark job in Dataproc.

I have a python script depends on a config.yaml file. And I notice that when I submit the job everything is executed under /tmp/.

How can I make available that config file in the /tmp/ folder?

At the moment, I get this error:

```
12/22/2020 10:12:27 AM root         INFO     Read config file.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/tmp/job-test4/train.py", line 252, in <module>
    run_training(args)
  File "/tmp/job-test4/train.py", line 205, in run_training
    with open(args.configfile, "r") as cf:
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'gs://network-spark-migrate/model/demo-config.yml'
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37685456/9671314). Try use the `--files` parameter  (See the [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/pyspark#--files)).

Comment: Thanks @cyxxy. I figured it out thanks your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below a snippet worked for me:

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark gs://network-spark-migrate/model/train.py --cluster train-spark-demo --region europe-west6 --files=gs://network-spark-migrate/model/demo-config.yml -- --configfile ./demo-config.yml
```