# Dataproc - pyspark job submit - how to access yaml file contained within a zip file passed using --files flag

Tags: python, apache-spark, google-cloud-dataproc

Below is my dataproc job submit command. I pass the project artifacts as a zip file to the "--files" flag

```
gcloud dataproc jobs submit pyspark --cluster=test_cluster --region us-central1 gs://test-gcp-project-123/main.py --files=gs://test-gcp-project-123/app_code_v2.zip
```

Following are the contents of "app_code_v2.zip".
[image]

I'm able to add "app_code_v2.zip" to the path using below code snippet, and access the python modules, but how do I access the "yml" files present in the zip package? those yml files contains the configs. Should I explicitly unzip the folder and copy to the working directory of the master node? Is there a better way to handle this?

```
if os.path.exists('app_code_v2.zip'):
   sys.path.insert(0, 'app_code_v2.zip')
```

Comment: You write a python code to read from the YAML file or dirty way to do it is to unzip it.You can also check --propertiesFile and this link-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65421933/submit-a-pyspark-job-with-a-config-file-on-dataproc

Comment: @Subash - I have more than 50 config files, so passing them one by one doesn't seem nice. So I zip it and pass it as an --archive argument. I was expecting it to get automatically extracted to the working directory of each executor.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to 1) extract the YAML files first, then add them explicitly to the flag like `--files=<zip>,<yaml>,...`, 2) or use `--archives=<zip>`, which will be automatically extracted to executor work dirs. In both ways, you can get the actual path of the file with [SparkFiles.get(filename)](https://spark.apache.org/docs/3.1.3/api/python/reference/api/pyspark.SparkFiles.get.html). See more info on the flags in this [doc](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/dataproc/jobs/submit/pyspark).

Note that files passed through `--files` and `--archives` are available for Spark **executors only**. This behavior is consistent with `spark-submit`. If you need the files to be accessible by Spark driver, consider using an [init action](https://cloud.google.com/dataproc/docs/concepts/configuring-clusters/init-actions) to put the files somewhere in the local filesystem explictly.

Comment: --archives=<zip>, the zip file doesn't get extracted if we are passing from a local directory. We should add a --archives=<zip>#extract_path to get it extracted to the working directory. If we are adding #, gcloud is expecting it to be a gcs path. With a local path, I am unable to give #.