# dataproc - unable to read archive files in pyspark

Tags: pyspark, google-cloud-dataproc

I run my pyspark code using the below command in dataproc.

```
gcloud dataproc batches submit pyspark src/features/spark_script.py \
  --project=$PROJECT_ID \
  --region=$REGION \
  --deps-bucket=$DEPS_BUCKET \
  --container-image=$CONTAINER_IMAGE \
  --service-account=$SERVICE_ACCOUNT \
  --subnet=$SUBNETWORK_URI \
  --properties deployMode=cluster \
  --py-files dist/src.zip \
  --files pyproject.toml \
  --archives dist/resources.zip
```

Within my code I am using the below code to read the YAML file present in resources.zip:

```py
with open("./resources/config/configuration.yaml", "r") as f:
  YAML_CONFIG = yaml.load(f, yaml.SafeLoader)
```

Still, it gives me

> FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory:
> './resources/config/configuration.yaml'

I tried giving `deployMode=cluster` as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62645635/dataproc-does-not-unpack-files-passed-as-archive). Even that didn't help.

It works only when I add the `--files` argument to the spark-submit command, but I have many config files like this to be used in the code, so `--archives` is the best option for me.

how can effectively debug and run this?

Comment: Hi @Tom J Muthirenthi, Can you try the solution provided in this [StackOverflow Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73100322/dataproc-pyspark-job-submit-how-to-access-yaml-file-contained-within-a-zip-f)? Let me know if this helps.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Spark --archives file not found error, exception from executor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74563500/spark-archives-file-not-found-error-exception-from-executor)